# Why do we average the losses of all elements of the batch if we typically should average the gradients (rather than the losses)?

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient

My `loss` output is

```
tensor([0.0430, 0.0443, 0.0430, 0.0430, 0.0443, 0.0466, 0.0466, 0.0466],
       grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

When I execute `loss.backward()`, I obtained `*** RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs`

In some places, they rather suggested `loss.mean().backward()` or `loss.sum().backward()`.

Why is `.mean().backward()` used, i.e. why do we average the losses of all elements of the batch if we typically should average the gradients (rather than the losses)?

Here is my [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13L723FV6uAIHdTHRrsumBJN2gvbMKNYG#scrollTo=l5PV94EVaAKM)

Answer (score 0):

Because by default when called upon a scalar it passes `[1]` as input to the backward function. If it's a tensor with more than one element then you should pass `[1,1,....1]` as the input to the backward.

```
loss.backward(torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... ,1]))
```

or

```
loss.backward(torch.ones(batch_size))
```

number of ones = number of elements in the 1D tensor in your case.

To answer why we use mean and all, because it acts as an normalizing term. Instead of letting all the loss of individual batch to affect in huge amount, we normalize the effect of it. Is this a problem? No. Rather, by scaling we get a much more reasonable sense about how the loss curve is behaving.

Comment: It is not that clean. I have never seen such practice.

Comment: @David.: Sorry which one you mean? What is not clean? If the backward is not applied to a scalar then yes this is the approach.

Comment: If I have batch_size = 256, I don't want to to write loss.backward(torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])). Do you have a solution for that issue? I am happy it might work, but I can't write that in my code

Comment: @David.: `torch.ones(batch_size)`

Comment: @David.: Check it now